# Como abrir una extension de chrome de manera automatica sin necesidad de tener que darle clic sobre la extension?

Tags: java, .bat

Tengo una extensión de Chrome que no realice yo, sino que es de un tercero y necesito que esta se ejecute o se abra automaticamente sin necesidad de darle clic directamente sobre la extension,intente realizarlo desde un archivo .bat pero este no se ejecuta ya que el desarrollo no encuentra el archivo en ninguna carpeta.Hay alguna otra manera de ejecutar estas extensiones de chrome de manera automatica?